# Azure web app uses IP outside of the outbound IP range

Tags: azure, azure-webapps, outbound, clientip

I have a .net core web application deployed as an Azuere web app. This web app makes an API call to another web application deployed on-premise.  The on-premise web applciaiton logs the IP address of the client applciation.

When the Azure web app makes an API call to an on-premises web application, the client IP address logged is different than the range of outbound IPs defined for the Azure app. I alwyas thought that the Azure web app uses one of the outbound Ips while communicating with other applciations. This does not seem to be the case.

1. I have added my Azure Web app to vnet. Does this have anything to do with the above observation?
2. Is there a proxy used by the Azure when Azure Web app makes external calls?

Comment: I faced the same issue as soon as I integrate the Azure Web App to a VNET. Somehow, the outbound IP switches from IPv4 to Ipv6 in this case.

Comment: I am curious about this. Is the on-prem web application also reside inside the vnet?